# How to exclude empty values with exporting with Pandas to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a data frame like so

```
0   2   5   12.0    1861.0  2230.0  NaN NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     IMG_0083.JPG
1   2   5   9.0     1201.0  1500.0  1.0 1156.0  1612.0  1584.0  1935.0  IMG_0124.JPG
2   2   5   3.0     1159.0  1391.0  2.0 2957.0  3249.0  1317.0  1588.0  IMG_0352.JPG
```

I need to export it to csv in the following format

```
0   2   5   12.0    1861.0  2230.0  IMG_0083.JPG
1   2   5   9.0     1201.0  1500.0  1.0 1156.0  1612.0  1584.0  1935.0  IMG_0124.JPG
2   2   5   3.0     1159.0  1391.0  2.0 2957.0  3249.0  1317.0  1588.0  IMG_0352.JPG
```

Not just replacing NaN with blank or some other value, but skipping NaN rows entirely.  It could be done in the data frame if you know a way, but really it just needs to happen on export to csv.  Any help?

**EDIT:**

For those curious, I'm trying to get my data into `.lst` format so I can convert it to `.rec` format using MXNet.  [I'm trying to use this](https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/image/image.html#image-iterator-for-object-detection) as a guide to the formatting.  I'm trying to train on this data with AWS SageMaker.  I'm getting all kinds of errors, [see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032344/unable-to-get-aws-sagemaker-to-read-recordio-files) if you know more about that particular topic.  I'm guessing on all this, but per the docs I linked to, I think I need the format in my question above.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea at all. Whoever is going to read that output file you want will likely have problems. Are you sure you need this design?

Comment: `df.replace(np.nan, '')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `Not just replacing NaN with blank or some other value` haha '}

Comment: @rafaelc I didn't see that coming. But like you said, it's rather meaningless.

Comment: @rafaelc see my edit.  I could be off regarding what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).tolist()).fillna('')
   0   1   2     3       4   ...    7     8     9     10            11
0   0   2   5  12.0  1861.0  ...                                      
1   1   2   5   9.0  1201.0  ...  1156  1612  1584  1935  IMG_0124.JPG
2   2   2   5   3.0  1159.0  ...  2957  3249  1317  1588  IMG_0352.JPG
[3 rows x 12 columns]
```

Or we can using [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180)

Comment: I think OP wants an uneven output file. For example, first line with only 5 values, next line with 10, next with 8, etc etc depending on how many non-na it has.